# Program to find whether a path exists between two given vertices of a graph

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, segmentation-fault, breadth-first-search

I wrote the following code in C to find whether there exists a path between two given vertices of a graph. Initially I ask the user for inputs, and then I use a breadth-first search to check whether there is a path between two specified vertices.

This code is working fine for some testcases, but throwing a segmentation fault for others. Where am I going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int v, e, e1, e2, t1, t2;

    printf("Enter num of vertices and edges: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &v, &e);
    int maze[v][v];

    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < v; j++)
            maze[i][j] = 0;

    printf("Enter edges:\n")
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &e1, &e2);
        maze[e1 - 1][e2 - 1] = 1;
        maze[e2 - 1][e1 - 1] = 1;
    }
    printf("The maze looks like:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            printf("%d ", maze[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("enter target edges: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &t1, &t2);

    //BFS starts from here.
    int queue[v * v];
    int k = 1;

    queue[0] = t1 - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
        if (maze[t1 - 1][i] == 1) {
            queue[k] = i;
             k++;
        }

    int bp, ep;

    bp = 0;
    ep = k;
    while (bp <= ep) {
        if (queue[bp] + 1 == t2) {
            printf("\npath exists\n");
            exit(0);
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < v; i++)
                if (maze[queue[bp + 1]][i] == 1) {
                    queue[k] = i;
                    k++;
                }       
        }
        bp = bp + 1;
        ep = k;
    }

    printf("\npath does'nt exist\n");
}
```

Testcases for which this code is working:

```
    Testcase-1:
    4 2
    1 2
    3 2
    1 3

    Testcase-2:
    4 2
    1 2
    3 2
    1 4

    TestCase-3:
    7 6
    0 1
    0 2
    1 3
    1 4
    1 6
    5 6
    1 6
```

Testcases for which I am getting a segmentation fault:

```
    TestCase-4:
    7 6
    0 1
    0 2
    1 3
    1 4
    1 6
    5 6
    0 6

    TestCase-5:
    7 6
    0 1
    0 2
    1 3
    1 4
    1 6
    5 6
    2 4
```

Comment: This is the point where you should start using a debugger. It should be able to tell you where the segmentation fault happened and let you inspect your variables at that time.

Comment: Fyi, this won't compile as is, which tells me it either never ran, or somehow you selectively dropped a semi-colon, seemingly impossible when one literally copy/pastes with no actual typing.

Comment: Do you mean you want to determine whether there is a *path* between a pair of vertices?  You should be able to determine whether there is an *edge* between them more or less directly from your representation of the graph.

Comment: I strongly suspect `if(maze[queue[bp+1]][i]==1)` is puking out-of-range on you. I'd run this in a debugger and if that pans out, figure out why. Specifically, `queue[bp+1]` contains either indeterminate data or a value out of the range of the superior dimension of `maze`.

Comment: If you are just interested in an edge, why not simply inspect `maze[t1-1][t2-1]`?

Comment: @Nico Schertler sorry for the wrong questions I actually need to determine path. Please help

Comment: Your input seems to have different formats. The first two cases seem to use 1-based indexing, the other two seem to use 0-based indexing.

Comment: @Nico Schertler thanks it's working if I change indexing to 1

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the errors in your test cases, you have several problems with your code, among them:

- you maintain `ep` as the index of the *next available* element of your queue, but your loop condition treats it as the *last used* element:

> ```
>     while (bp <= ep) {
> ```

- you do not traverse the edges of the first vertex enqueued.  You look past it to the second:

> ```
>                 if (maze[queue[bp + 1]][i] == 1) {
> ```

- you look up to *two* vertices past the last one enqueued (same lines already quoted)
- you have no mechanism to avoid visiting the same vertex more than once, so

  1. you use quadratic queue space when in principle you need only linear,
  2. but even that's not enough, because in the event that the start vertex is part of a loop but is not connected to the desired end vertex, your BFS will never terminate (until the program crashes).

Comment: This condition if (maze[queue[bp + 1]][i] == 1 is not to check the elements it is to add the children of next element into queue secondly you are correct with statement I use quadratic space but the program does execute please try it once

Comment: Can you suggest me a method to do it in linear space please

Comment: @karthikreddy, using linear queue space follows directly from avoiding enqueuing the same vertex more than once (ever).  You cannot then need more queue space, even in your somewhat simplistic queue implementation, than there are vertices in total.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is correct but in the testcases I started indexing from '0' in later ones that's why I got a segmentation fault so if the vertices labeling starts from 1 this code works fine.